# Generic term for hoverover on video progress bar that displays frame at that point in time?

Tags: video, video-streaming, video-processing, terminology

Some video media players/editors have a feature whereby hovering over the progress bar will display a thumbnail of the video at (or around) that point in time. What is the generic term for this software feature?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Search for `video timeline thumbs` or `timeline preview thumbs`...

Comment: @VC.One reason I'm after the term is for reproducible instructions, e.g. "use the <term> to quickly locate the 4 blue slides in the hour long presentation"

Comment: "scrubber" is what I've used in the past